# Indexes not appearing in sys tables on Azure Secondary

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm running the following query on an AZure SQL Read Only secondary to determine which indexes are being used. But some of the indexes are not being returned in the query.  I must be missing something obvious but I can't see what part of the statement is filtering my results !

```
SELECT
  objects.name AS Table_name,
  indexes.name AS Index_name,
  dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks,
  dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans,
  dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates
FROM
  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
INNER JOIN sys.objects ON dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = 
  objects.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.index_id = 
  dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id AND dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = 
indexes.OBJECT_ID
WHERE objects.name = 'BookingDiary'
ORDER BY
  objects.name , dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates DESC
```

[image: SSMS screenshot]

Comment: An index would not exist in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` until it  is used at least once.

Comment: thanks Denis, when I was posting the question i started to take a step back and after a cup of tea, logically came to that conclusion..  I think leaving it here might help someone else at some point!